# Show only filtered items in ReactNative Flat List

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

When user navigates to a screen(Let's say screen A), I'm getting users' data from an API and show them in a flatlist. In this view there's a search bar. When user search a name (to find the contact number) it filters the data from the flatlist. It works. But I have another requirement. I need to do the search not only from the list but also in phone contact of the persons. Let's say that person A search the name 'Rahul' on search bar. If there's any name matches in the flat list (which is showing the data from API) I want to show that and also I need to show the contact details of 'Rahul' if this name is stored in phone contact. So what I did was , I used two flat lists(Let' say FlatList A and FlatList B, FlatList A- API data | Flat List B- phone contact data) . One to show the API data and the other one to show the phone contact data. But my issue is when user search a name and clear the text , all records of phone contact is showing the flat list. I only want to show the item of phone contact in flat list (flat list B) , not to show the all phone contact. This is what I tried.

```
class UsersListScreen extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data:[],
        phContacts:[],


    };
    this.usersData= [];
    this.phoneContactData =[];

}

componentDidMount(){
   this.props.getUsersData();
   this.getPhoneContacts();
}

componentDidUpdate(previousProps){
    if(previousProps.usersList != this.props.usersList){
        this.setState({data:this.props.usersList})

    }
}

getPhoneContacts(){
    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
        PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS,
            {
              'title': 'Contacts',
              'message': 'This app would like to access your contacts.'
            }
          ).then(() => {
            Contacts.checkPermission((err, permission) => {
              if (err) throw err;

              if (permission === 'undefined') {
                Contacts.requestPermission((err, permission) => {
                })
              }
              if (permission === 'authorized') {
                Contacts.getAll((err, contacts) => {
                    this.usersData = this.props.usersList
                    this.phoneContactData = contacts
                })
              }
              if (permission === 'denied') {
                console.log('denied')
              }
            })
          })
    }
}

//Search Filter
searchFilter =text=>{

    const filteredData = this.usersData.filter(item => {  
        const itemData = `${item.userName.toUpperCase()}`;
        const textData = text.toUpperCase();
                return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;    
        }); 

    this.setState({ data: filteredData });  

    const filteredPhoneContactData = this.phoneContact.filter(item=>{
        const itemData2 = `${item.displayName.toUpperCase()}`;
        const textData = text.toUpperCase();

          return itemData2.indexOf(textData) > -1;  

        });
        this.setState({ phContacts: filteredPhoneContactData });  
}


render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.mainContainer}>

            <TextInput 
            style={styles.searchInputStyle}
            placeholder="Search user"
            onChangeText={text=>this.searchFilter(text)}
            />
            </View>  
            {this.state.isLoading ?
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" /> :
                <FlatList  
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                data={this.state.data}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}/>  
            }

            {this.state.phContacts ? 
            <FlatList  

                                data={this.state.phContacts}
                                renderItem={this.renderContacts}

            /> : null}

        </View>

    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> Don't render flat list B if the input is clear.

```js
{
(this.state.phContacts && !inputText) ? 
  <FlatList  
    data={this.state.phContacts}
    renderItem={this.renderContacts}
  /> 
  :
  null
}
```

But as you're not maintaining the input query in the state, just clear the list when the input is empty

```js
searchFilter = text => { 
  if(!text) {
    this.setState({phContacts: [], data: []});
    return;
  }
  ...
  ...
}
```

Comment: Not working bro. I don't want to clear the flatlist with API data (FlatList A) , so I only do the change as if(!text) {
    this.setState({phContacts: []);
    return;
  }

Then it clears the FlatList B data , but some data from FlatList A also get cleared.